# Как правильно передать id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Знакомлюсь с возможностями PyQt5 и возникла такая задача: есть список имен, которые берутся из базы и выводятся в виджете QListWidget:

```
self.list = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
for key, value in res_usr.items():
    self.list.addItem(value)
self.vbox.addWidget(self.list)

self.list.itemClicked.connect(self.getChatWithUser)

def selectionChanged(self, item):
    print("Вы кликнули: {}".format(item.text()))
```

Здесь есть словарь res_usr={1:''username1', 2:'username2'}, в котором собраны из базы пары значений id:username, перебирая в цикле я вывожу в QListWidget эти имена usernam1, username2. Идея такая, что при клике на имя должна вызываться функция getChatWithUser, в которую хотелось бы передавать не имя, а соответствующий id.

Проблема в том, что в item.text() приходит именно то, что отображается в виджете, т.е. имя, а мне нужно передать id. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то скрыто передать id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for key, value in res_usr.items():
    item = QListWidgetItem(self.list)
    item.setText(value)
    item.setData(Qt.UserRole, key)

def selectionChanged(self, item):
    print("Вы кликнули: {}".format(item.data(Qt.UserRole)))
```

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, спасибо за ответ